# what happens when stringWithFormat format has no type placeholders but has arguments

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

Suppose I have a method like this

```
+ (NSString *)stringWithObject:(id)object format:(NSString *)format
{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, object];

    NSLog(@"%@", string);

    return string;
}
```

The `object` parameter is never `nil` but the format argument passed into the method might either be

```
NSString *formatWithPlaceholder = @"object: %@"
```

or

```
NSString *formatWithoutPlaceholder = @"No object";
```

so if `formatWithoutPlaceholder` is passed into the method as the format argument, the console output is correct and there are no warnings or errors, but will this cause other problems? I feel like there is something wrong about the usage of `stringWithFormat:` like this.

Comment: The unused parameters fall on the floor.  Other than the fact that they make the floor sticky there's no problem.  To have format specifiers without parameters, on the other hand, can lead to the end of the Universe as we know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing bad happens when the format string has fewer format specifiers than the number of parameters supplied: your code is valid for both format strings.

However, when the opposite situation happens (more format specifiers than the parameters) you get undefined behavior.